# how to ignore pre-existent documents on initial results of added observers?

Tags: meteor

My application is watching **added** documents with `cursor.observe`.

Quoting [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe):

> added will immediately be called as necessary to deliver the initial
>   results of the query, if any.

In my case, I just want to treat documents added during client life time, and do nothing with pre-existent ones.
So, **how to ignore pre-existent documents** on *initial results of the query*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a hidden `_suppress_initial` argument to `observe` that gets around this: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#why-does-observe-fire-a-bunch-of-added-events-for-existing-documents